# Scala message bus implementation by Actors?

Tags: scala, message, actor, bus

I want to implement some kind of message bus in one of my Scala applications. The features would be:

- ability to subscribe to 1 .. N types of messages
- messages may have payloads
- loose coupling (nodes only hold a reference to the bus)
- lightweight (no fully blown enterprise message queue etc.)

What I plan to do is to implement all nodes and the bus itself as standard Scala actors. For example I want to define a trait `Subscriber` like this:

```
trait Subscriber[M <: Message[_]] {
  this: Actor =>
  def notify(message: M)
}
```

Ideally mixing in this trait should already register the subscription for the type `M`.

So does this idea make sense? Are there better approaches to realize a message bus?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I am the PO of Akka

Hi Itti,

This has already been done for you in Akka, the Actor Kernel: [www.akka.io](http://www.akka.io)

Docs: http://doc.akkasource.org/routing-scala

Pub/Sub: [Akka Listeners](https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/routing/Listeners.scala)
Routers: [Akka Routers](https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/routing/Routers.scala)
Convenience: [Akka Routing](https://github.com/jboner/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/routing/Routing.scala)

Comment: I take your answer as a "yes you can realize a bus-like system by usage of actors". I will probably do my own implementation but will invest some time looking into what Akka can provide. Thank you!